# How to store user preferences in react native app?

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I am making an app having some data that should be persisted when the app installs. This data can be changed later by users. How do I store the data only one time when app installs and not every time when the screen is opened?
Basically these are all settings of the app with default values (User Preferences) that can be changed later. 
I have tried following:

```
_retrieveData = async() => {
    try {
        await AsyncStorage.multiGet('r1','r2','r3','r4','r5','fix','box').then(data =>{
            Utils.r1 = data[0][1];
            Utils.r2 = data[1][1];
            Utils.r3 = data[2][1];
            Utils.r4 = data[3][1];
            Utils.r5 = data[4][1];
            Utils.fix = data[5][1];
            Utils.modlShow = data[6][1];
            alert('data got successfully'); 
            if(!Utils.r1 || !Utils.r2 || !Utils.r3 || !Utils.r4 || !Utils.r5 || !Utils.fix || !Utils.modlShow) {
                 AsyncStorage.multiSet(['r1','1'],['r2','2'],['r3','3'],['r4','4'],
                    ['r5','5'],['fix','3'],['box','true']);
            }
        })
    } catch {
        alert('Error in retrieving data');
    }
}
```

I am getting following error:

> undefined is not a function(evaluating 
>   'requestKeys.map(function(key){   return[key,map[key]];   })')

How do I remove the error and get the values? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd try to either use `await`, or `then`, not both. As in: `const data = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(...);`

Comment: @Kraylog Getting same error even after removing `await`

Answer (score 0):

```
_retrieveData = async() => {
try {
    const data = await AsyncStorage.multiGet('r1','r2','r3','r4','r5','fix','box')
    const Utils = {}
    Utils['r1'] = data[0][1];
    Utils['r2'] = data[1][1];
    Utils['r3'] = data[2][1];
    Utils['r4'] = data[3][1];
    Utils['r5'] = data[4][1];
    Utils['fix'] = data[5][1];
    Utils['modlShow']= data[6][1];
    alert('data got successfully'); 
    if(!Utils.r1 || !Utils.r2 || !Utils.r3 || !Utils.r4 || !Utils.r5 || !Utils.fix || !Utils.modlShow) {
         return AsyncStorage.multiSet(['r1','1'],['r2','2'],['r3','3'],['r4','4'],
                ['r5','5'],['fix','3'],['box','true']);
        }
} catch {
    alert('Error in retrieving data');
}
```

}